# Why this MySQL date conversion returns NULL?

Tags: mysql

Trying to convert a date format into a MySQL date:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('8/3/2011 13:30','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i');
```

but it returns NULL. Note that this similar query works:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('8/3/2011 13:30','%m/%d/%Y');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%h` expects a number from 01 to 12.  13 is invalid.

Try `%H` or `%k` instead.  They're for 24-hour times.

Comment: Great! How I didn't notice?!? :O