# MySQL STR_TO_DATE() function returns null

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I wanted to convert my date format From `MMMM dd,yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I tried using the following:

```
SET @dt_to = STR_TO_DATE(dateTo, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

but returns a `NULL` value.

How will I convert my date to `yyyy-MM-dd` format in MySQL?

**EDITED:**

I am creating a procedure in which the value of `dateTo` was received in the parameter. It is a date in `MMMM dd, yyyy` format. E.g. `October 10, 2015`.

**NOTE:**

The whole query does not return `NULL` when I use:

```
SET @dt_to = dateTo;
```

Comment: show sample data or better create an sqlfiddle

Comment: what is the value of dateTo?

Comment: [FYI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7758625/2749470)

Comment: As stated in my question, I was trying to convert a date from `MMMM dd, yyyy` format. Therefore, the value of my dateTo would be any date in that format.

Comment: Why did you write `%d-%m-%Y`, when that is not your input format? o.O No wonder it didn't work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert the date format first you need to use STR_TO_DATE to convert the input string to a date value

```
SET @dt_to = STR_TO_DATE(dateTo, '%M %d,%Y');
```

and then convert that date value to your required format

```
SET @dt_converted = DATE_FORMAT(dt_to, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

or all in 1 go

```
SET @dt_to = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateTo, '%M %d,%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's returning null then that means the extracted datetime value is illegal. You can try like below. See [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for more information.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('October 10, 2015','%M %d,%Y');
```

Comment: And the definition of "illegal" seems to vary between versions and flavors.
e.g. `SELECT str_to_date("4:00PM", "%l:%i%p")` yields `16:00:00` on MariaDB 5.5.5, but `NULL` on MySQL 5.7.18. For latter, you can get away with any year/date: `SELECT str_to_date("1111-11-11 4:00PM", "%Y-%m-%d %l:%i%p")` (and then wrap in 'TIME()' if you just need that).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting `NULL` because I was only supplying a month and year. Some versions of MySQL infer the day (1), but making it explicit fixed this for me.